# How to use Service Principal/Managed Identity to access Azure App Configuration?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-app-configuration

I need to disable Local Authentication Methods (Access Keys) for Azure App Configuration Stores.
Currently for an ASP.NET Framework application, I am using the following for accessing the App Configuration Store from my application:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="configBuilders" type="System.Configuration.ConfigurationBuildersSection, System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" restartOnExternalChanges="false" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>

<configBuilders>
    <builders>
        <add name="MyConfigStore" mode="Greedy" connectionString="${ConnectionString}" type="Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.AzureAppConfigurationBuilder, Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.AzureAppConfiguration" />
        <add name="Environment" mode="Greedy" type="Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.EnvironmentConfigBuilder, Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.Environment" />
    </builders>
</configBuilders>
```

Here the value of `${ConnectionString} = "Endpoint=https://<app_config>.azconfig.io;Id=<Id>;Secret=<Access Key>"`

Now in order to access the App Configuration through the ASP.NET application, I created a Service Principal, generated a secret to use.

I have stored the **CLIENT_ID**, **TENANT_ID** and **CLIENT_SECRET** values. I have also assigned the **App Configuration Data Reader** role to the Service Principal.

I also have a managed identity which I can use.

Now what change do I need to make at the application side in order to access the App Configuration through the ASP.NET application?

Answer (score 0):

Check the below Workaround to access the `App Configuration` in the `.NET Framework` Application.

In `Azure Portal` => `App Configuration` => `Configuration explorer`,
create new `Key-value`.

[image]

- Install the below `NuGet Packages`

```cs
Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.AzureAppConfiguratio - Version 1.0.0
Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.Environment - Version 2.0.0
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager - Version 7.0.0
```

***Configuration Section from my `Web.config` file:***

```cs
<configSections>
    <section name="configBuilders" type="System.Configuration.ConfigurationBuildersSection, System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" restartOnExternalChanges="false" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>

  <configBuilders>
    <builders>
      <add name="AzureAppConfig" mode="Greedy" connectionString="Endpoint=https://AppConfigName.azconfig.io;Id=XqdS-l2-s0:****/;Secret=****" type="Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.AzureAppConfigurationBuilder, Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.AzureAppConfiguration" />
      <add name="Environment" mode="Greedy" type="Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.EnvironmentConfigBuilder, Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.Environment" />
    </builders>
  </configBuilders>

  <appSettings configBuilders="Environment,AzureAppConfig">
    <add key="AppName" value=".NET Framework Sample" />
  </appSettings>
```

**Reading Config Value:**

In Controller,

```cs
   public ActionResult Index()
        {
            string FromAppConfig = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TestApp:Settings:Message"];
            string FromWebConfig = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppName"];
            ViewBag.FromAppConfig = FromAppConfig;
            ViewBag.FromWebConfig = FromWebConfig;
            return View();
        }
```

***In View.cshtml:***

```cs
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div>
    <h2>  Value from App Configuration - @ViewBag.FromAppConfig</h2>
    <h2>  Value from Web.Config File - @ViewBag.FromWebConfig</h2>
</div>
```

***OutPut:***
[image]

References taken from [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/quickstart-dotnet-app#connect-to-an-app-configuration-store)

Comment: In the web.config section, what's the connection string's ID and Secret?

Comment: In `Azure Portal` => Open your `App Configuration` => `Access Keys`  => Under `Primary key`, copy the connection string. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Zb7a.png)

Comment: Paste the Copied Connection string in your `Web.config` file.

Comment: This is what I don't want to use. I need to use either a Service Principal or a Managed Identity for the access. This is what I am currently using.

Comment: Ok..Will work on it and let you know.

Comment: Do you want to use `Azure KeyVault`?

Comment: Some values in the key value pair in the `App Configuration` are stored in Key Vault. Do you mean using `Key Vault` instead of `Azure App Configuration`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250887/discussion-between-harshitha-and-aj31).

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `endpoint` instead of the `connectionString` parameter when you config your builders. This will tell the system to use the `DefaultAzureCredential` to connect to Azure App Configuration.

I would also put the "Environment" builder *before* the "AzureAppConfig" builder, so environment variables are available to the AppConfig builder during loading. It looks something like this:

```xml
  <configBuilders>
    <builders>
      <add name="Environment" mode="Greedy" type="Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.EnvironmentConfigBuilder, Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.Environment" />
      <add name="AzureAppConfig" mode="Greedy" endpoint="https://<AppConfigName>.azconfig.io" type="Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.AzureAppConfigurationBuilder, Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.AzureAppConfiguration" />
    </builders>
  </configBuilders>
```

Given you want to use the service principal, you should make `CLIENT_ID`, `TENANT_ID` and `CLIENT_SECRET` available as environment variables, so the `DefaultAzureCredential` will pick them up automatically.

You should NEVER put any secrets in the web.config file. You can find more information about the App Configuration builder library from the link below.

https://github.com/aspnet/MicrosoftConfigurationBuilders/blob/main/docs/KeyValueConfigBuilders.md#azureappconfigurationbuilder

Comment: Since managed identity is also available for the service, it might be preferable to use it and avoid having to use CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET and TENANT_ID. In fact, the managed identity should be used automatically when accessing an App Configuration.

Comment: Right. The `DefaultAzureCredential` will go through a list of child credentials, including the service principal and managed identity. If you don't provide those CLIENT_* env variables, the managed identity will be attempted. Same code :)

Comment: How do I use `DefaultAzureCredential` ? I mean I am using the following to get a value from Azure App Config - `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Key1"]`. So what should I modify?

Comment: The `AzureAppConfigurationBuilder` library automatically uses the `DefatulAzureCredential` when you specify the `endpoint` instead of the `connectionString`.